# tabularx within gb4e linguistic example within footnote - What width do I use?

Tags: footnotes, indentation, tabularx, gb4e

I am trying to use a tabularx table within a gb4e linguisti example within a footnote, and if I simply set the tabularx width to \textwidth, the resulting table goes way too far to the right. Thus, the following code produces the output below:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

blabla\footnote{
\lipsum[1]

\begin{exe}
\ex \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
Some text & \lipsum[1]
\end{tabularx}
\end{exe}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To what width should I be setting tabularx, and more generally, how would I find out?

Edit: Note that my problem isn't the result of an interaction between gb4e examples and footnotes; rather, both in footnotes and in linguistic examples,  setting the tabularx to \textwidth will result in the table spanning beyond the margins, doing it within both at once only exacerbates the problem. So an answer to any of the following questions would be useful:

- Do footnotes use a separate textwidth or are they just indented, and if so, how do I find out how far?
- Does gb4e use a separate length for textwidth or does it just indent examples, and if so, how do I find out how far?
- Once I know how big the indentation is, how do I set the tabularx to the correct width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it sets `\linewidth` just like a standard list so:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

blabla\footnote{
\lipsum[1]

\begin{exe}
\ex \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
Some text & \lipsum[1]
\end{tabularx}
\end{exe}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you might also want `[t]` to make it align at the top.